# Select2 4.0 and Knockout 3.1 select not allowing selection

Tags: knockout.js, html-select, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I'm trying to get knockout (version 3.1) to work with a select2 (version 4.0rc2).

I am unable to get the select to accept input and have an initial selection. The select seems to be read only.

Below is a fiddle demonstrating my problem. I tested this on Chrome (version 40.0.2214.115 m).

http://jsfiddle.net/R8UF5/402/

JavaScript:

```
ko.utils.setValue = function (property, newValue) { if (ko.isObservable(property)) property(newValue); else property = newValue; };

ko.bindingHandlers.select2 = {
init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
    var obj = valueAccessor(),
        allBindings = allBindingsAccessor(),
        lookupKey = allBindings.lookupKey;

    $(element).select2(obj);

    ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "select2-selected", function (data) {
        if ('selectedValue' in allBindingsAccessor()) {
            ko.utils.setValue(allBindingsAccessor().selectedValue, data.choice);
        }
    });

    ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
        $(element).select2('destroy');
    });
},
update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
    var options = allBindingsAccessor().select2Options || {};

    for (var property in options) {
        $(element).select2(property, ko.utils.unwrapObservable(options[property]));
    }

    $(element).trigger('change');
}
};

// Constructor for an object with two properties
var Country = function(name, population, price) {
    this.countryName = name;
    this.countryPopulation = population;
    this.price = price;
    this.id = price;
    this.text = name;
};

var countries = [ new Country("UK", 65000000,1), new Country("USA", 320000000,2), new Country("Sweden", 29000000,3)];
var viewModel = {
    availableCountries : ko.observableArray(countries),
    selectedCountry : ko.observable(countries[1])
};
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

HTML:

```
Your country:
<select style="width:100%;" data-bind="options: $root.availableCountries,
                   optionsText: 'countryName',
                   value: selectedCountry, 
                   select2: {  }">
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's an updated, working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/R8UF5/404/

The main issue that you were hitting is that Knockout.js binds all options with the same `value` attribute, which is blank, and Select2 couldn't handle it correctly. I was able to fix this by passing `optionsValue: 'id'` into the `data-bind` attribute, which correctly set the `value` attribute to the id.

The other issue is that Select2 no longer properly handles selecting options with the same `value`, which I've opened a ticket about: https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3163

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't select the desired initial value. Also I wan't it to update the object and not just the Id since the object is used elsewhere in my real program.

Comment: Does the "ko.utils.setValue" do anything in the code? I have found only one occurance.

Comment: Btw you can fix the issue with placehollder if you have access to the source array and do something like myOptions.unshift({ id: undefined, text: undefined });

Comment: @kevin brown I think the real problem here is that the select2: binding is not reactive. You just set it to an empty object.  In the old select2  3.x+ code, I could write { initSelection: function() { return thisKnockoutViewModel.Property(); } } - you don't seem to have a way to initialize the value on start-up.  I'm trying to follow the Custom Data Adapter thing, but it's so weird, and I am so puzzled why you say it shouldn't be needed often, as any business app I write seems to need it.